# How to Populate Multiple Form Fields from onClick of Multiple EJS Data Fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, onclick, ejs

I apologize if this is answered elsewhere, please point me in that direction.

From a dynamically populated list, I've figured out how to click one item in the list and have that text go to my form input.

My ejs code...

```
 <% for(var i=0; i<BeerList.length; i++) {%>
    <div>
      <a onclick="document.getElementById('beerName').value='<%= BeerList[i].beer.beer_name %>'" >
        <span><%= BeerList[i].beer.beer_name %></span>
      </a>
    </div>
 <% } %>
```

...will show a list of beer names...

**Raspy Angel Bourbon Stout**

**MEOWSA!**

**Vă-da**

**Magnanimous IPA**

**B-Bomb (2019)**

And when I click on a beer name, that one name will populate my form input field.

Form code...

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="beerName" />
</form>
```

This works fine, but I can't figure out how to add a separate piece of data to a separate form input.
For example, if I want to include the Brewery Name in addition to the Beer Name, I try something like this...

```
 <% for(var i=0; i<BeerList.length; i++) {%>
    <div>
      <a onclick="document.getElementById('beerName').value='<%= BeerList[i].beer.beer_name %>'" >
        <span><%= BeerList[i].beer.beer_name %></span>
        <span><%= BeerList[i].brewery.brewery_name %></span>
      </a>
    </div>
 <% } %>


<form>
   <input type="text" id="beerName" />
   <input type="text" id="breweryName" />
</form>
```

This obviously won't work as my onClick isn't even able to look for id=breweryName. If I give the **form** the id like **form id="beerANDbrewery"**, I don't know how to go about getting each item into the appropriate input field.

Thank you so much for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function that handles both cases. The function should take as parameters the values you want.

```
<% for(var i=0; i<BeerList.length; i++) {%>
    <div>
        <a onclick="addText('<%= BeerList[i].beer.beer_name %>', '<%= BeerList[i].brewery.brewery_name %>') " >
        <span><%= BeerList[i].beer.beer_name %></span>
        <span><%= BeerList[i].brewery.brewery_name %></span>
       </a>
    </div>
<% } %>

<form>
   <input type="text" id="beerName" />
   <input type="text" id="breweryName" />
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var addText = function(beerName, breweryName) {
        document.getElementById('beerName').value = beerName;
        document.getElementById('breweryName').value = breweryName;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Dimitris, thank you so much for your answer! It's not working yet. A few follow-up questions. 
I think there's an extra 't' in the initial var name? I've fixed this.
And to what are the **beer**,**brewery** names in the function(**beer**, **brewery**) related?

Comment: Ah, I think I see why it wasn't working (in addition to the extra 't' in the var), the function names (beer, brewery) needed to be the same as the .value = <names>. I've marked yours as the answer, but maybe you can confirm my thoughts on this?